# How to get the particular data from string using regex in scala

Tags: java, regex, scala

I have an String which consists of date and i want to pick only a particular field. How to extract in scala.

My sample string is :

> Monday, 4th Aug : shipping

I want the string

> **4 Aug**

How to do this is in scala

Comment: why downvote... first give the answer and then downvote.. that's ok

Comment: I wasn't the down-voter, but it's good to include code you've tried first, which is probably why someone down-voted.

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but why should someone have to answer a question before downvoting it ?

Comment: The downvotes are (I'm assuming) because you've asked a question that has been answered many, many times before, You tagged it regex, so you knew that might be involved, but don't seem (as far as we can tell from your question) to have looked into Scala or Java's regex functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way using a crude regex:

```
val str = "Monday, 4th Aug : shipping"
val regex = "^Monday, (\\d+)[a-z]{2} ([A-z]{3}) : [A-z]+$".r

scala> Option(str) collect { case regex(day, month) => s"$day $month" }
res130: Option[String] = Some(4 Aug)
```

I used `Option` and `collect`, so that I can return `None` if there is no match. I used `regex(day, month)` to pattern match the capture groups out of the regex, and then use them to create the new string. To handle matching only days of the week/actual months, you may want to improve on that regex with ORs or something. Or if you don't really care, you can change "Monday" to match some string.

eg.

```
val regex = "^(Monday|Tuesday), (\\d+)[a-z]{2} ([A-z]{3}) : [A-z]+$".r

scala> Option(str) collect { case regex(_, day, month) => s"$day $month" }
res132: Option[String] = Some(4 Aug)
```

Comment: can't i start from (\\d+) it wont take monday i think

Comment: You can replace it with `.*`, if you want.

Comment: but .* is matching every character ... @Thanx m-z ... I got the answer .. I eliminated the  Monday part and everything is working fine ..